# Downloading multiple pdf's from website using web-scraping

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

Hi everyone I need some help with my web-scraper as I want to download 100s of pdf files from https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/ as I'm trying to download as much biomedical pdfs as I can from the website. I have built the web-scraper using some answers from this website but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

My aim is to download the pdfs and store them in specific folder and I would grateful for any help with this.

```
url="https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles"
response = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))



url_list = []
  for el in links:
if(el['href'].startswith('http')):
url_list.append(el['href'])
   else:
    url_list.append("https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com" + el['href'])

    print(url_list)



for url in url_list:
print(url)
pathname ="C:/Users/SciencePDF/"
fullfilename = os.path.join(pathname, url.replace("https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles", 
 ""))
print(fullfilename)
request.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

Comment: Please fix the indents in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your script to make it work. When you try the following script, it will create a folder within the same directory where the location of your script is and store the downloaded pdf files within the newly created folder.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com{}'
url = 'https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

foldername = url.split("/")[-1]
os.mkdir(foldername)

for pdf in soup.select("a[data-track-action='Download PDF']"):
    filename = pdf['href'].split("/")[-1]
    fdf_link = base.format(pdf['href']) + ".pdf"
    with open(f"{foldername}/{filename}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(fdf_link).content)
```